# android: design an activity with an scrollable part

Tags: android, scrollview

my activity contains 4 section as follow:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

what is the correct layout properties for scrollview?

Comment: which part are you trying to scroll?

Comment: The `ScrollView` must contain the part that is supposed to scroll.

Comment: inside the scrollview there's a linearlayout...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice :Pardon me but your answer makes me laugh.For two reasons first it doesn't answer the OP and second for the frugalness of the text. :D

Comment: `<ScrollView></ScrollView>` This looks empty to me. Did you leave something out?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice excuse me bro, do you read the question?

Comment: Sorry. I was just thrown off by the empty `ScrollView`.

Comment: @MasoudNazari Look at the tags again. The opening and closing tags have nothing in them. You have to put the `</ScrollView>` tag on the other side of your last `</LinearLayout>` tag (or the opening ScrollView tag before the opening tag for the previous LinearLayout, I don't know which layout you intended to use for your ScrollView) for their to be a LinearLayout inside the ScrollView.

Comment: You should use a Linear Layout instead of a Relative for the parent container, and give your views weights. The match_parent attribute it a bad idea for a scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- put your scrolling stuff here it needs
       to exceed the height of the view to scroll -->
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I believe this should work..**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- your layouts.. -->
            <!-- layouts in here will be in the scrollview -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't include the layouts which are outside the `ScrollView`.